# changing CSS for specific ID used on multiple tags through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to hide all div's except the first of a certain id. I tried to write my own jquery but it seems to not be working.

```
    $("div.hero-featureSwap:not(:first)").css({display:none});
```

would this hide all the div tags that have an ID of "hero-featureSwap" except the first one? That is my end result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the value in the CSS object must be a string:

```
.css({display: "none"});
```

or:

```
.css("display", "none");
```

Or you could just use jQuery's `hide()` method:

```
$("div.hero-featureSwap:not(:first)").hide();
```

Comment: would this work if the hero-featureSwap is an ID and not a class tag?

Comment: If it's an ID then there can only be one of them, so `:not(:first)` makes no sense. It's the only one, so it's always first.

Comment: I was trying to had the divs in a carousel because they were overlapping eachother. By doing this, I hide all except the first one. Is there a CSS property that will hide the 2nd+ divs?

Comment: `display: none` is the correct property. Is your question about the property or the selector?

Comment: But it sounds like your confusion is about the proper way to construct the HTML, and the difference between classes and IDs.